# URL Query Param Djangorestframework

Tags: django, parameters, django-rest-framework, url-parameters

I was wondering how I would filter for two different charfield variables in the rest framework. Currently my URL is like this `/internal/api/management/ticket/?status=Awaiting%20Staff%20Reply`however how would I pass both "Awaiting Staff Reply and also "Open" into that url for filter.

I have searched around a fair bit but nothing has come up yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to answer if we can't see, how you applying the filtering feature in your view.
I can already tell you you would need custom filter backend.

To separate the values, you just need to agree on a fixed separator that would probably won't exists in the value's content itself. Typically for single word values it would be comma, so if you think comma won't exists in status text, then you should go with it.

```
Awaiting%20Staff%20Reply,Open
```

Then you can handle the status value in custom filtering class or so, depending on what type of backend are you using.

Comment: Yup went the custom route and it is working with separating them using commas